# Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase, crash

I've published my app days ago on the Play Store. Yesterday, Firebase sent me a message with the following error:

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction ()
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.a ()
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss ()
com.kerbalosapp.helloworld.MainActivity$3$1.run ()
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:725)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:92)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:153)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5341)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:511)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:929)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

All the answers posted in similar problems suggest that the problem is with getChildFragmentManager(), but I don't have any nested fragments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding this function inside the MainActivity:

```
public boolean isRunning() {
    return getWindow().getDecorView().isShown();
}
```

Before committing any transaction I use `isRunning()` to check activity state.